# Dart check String has only valid characters

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to check if password field has only allowed characters.

There is call contains, but I'm not sure how to properly create regexp.

From docs:

```
string.contains(new RegExp(r'[A-Z]'))
```

Allowed characters I need to check:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 ! " # $ % &' ( ) * + , -. / : ; < = > ? @ [ \] ^ _` { | } ~
```

Also I need to find out what exact symbols 'restricted' symbols were entered.

As a possible solution - I can split password into characters and validate each character against allowed table. Not sure this one easiest. Also would need to escape $ and \ in allowed characters table.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't make it to work using regExp, so built this function to do find illegal characters:

```
String getRestrictedCharacters(String string){
      const allowedCharacters = r"""abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~""";
      Set<String> restricted = Set();
      final split = string.split('');
      split.forEach((c) {
        if (!allowedCharacters.contains(c)) {
          restricted.add(c);
        }
      });
      if (restricted.isEmpty){
        return null;
      } else {
        return restricted.join("");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for a character sequence which contains other characters then allowable.

To do that use:

> [^a-zA-Z0-9......]*

Notice that the caret (^) at the beginning of the character sequence means "anything except the following".

If it returns a non-empty string, the password has forbidden characters.